# How to combine 2 CoreData predicates in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a function:

```
open func getAllCarsCount(from garages: [Garage], with categories: Set<Category> = []) -> Int {
    var returnCount = 0
    let context = DBContext.defaultContext

    var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
    for category in categories {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(carHasCategories, $c, $c.categoryName == %@ ).@count > 0", category.categoryName)
        predicates.append(predicate)
    }

    for garage in garage {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "garageNbr = \(garage.garageNbr) AND active = 1" )
        predicates.append(predicate)
    }

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Car")
    request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)

    do {
        let count = try context.count(for: request)
        returnCount += count
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could  not get all cars count. ", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return returnCount
}
```

in which I'm trying to get a number of cars which has one of the given `categories`.
But I need to combine 2 predicates. So what I want is:

To get ALL cars count from the given `garages` array where they are `active`, `garageNbr` are matched AND which has one of the given categories. Currently my code does not work correctly and I would really appreciate if someone could help me with it

Database structure looks like this:

`Garage`: `garageNbr`, `name`, `active`

`Car`: `name`

`Category`: `categoryName`

And they have relationships:

`Garage`:
    Relationship: `garageHasCars`
    Destination: `Car`
    Inverse: `carInGarage`

`Car`:
    Relationship: `carInGarage`
    Destination: `Garage`
    Inverse: `garageHasCars`

```
Relationship: `carHasCategories`
Destination: `Category`
Inverse: `categoryHasCars`
```

`Category`:
    Relationship: `categoryHasCars`
    Destination: `Car`
    Inverse: `carHasCategories`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand it correctly:

- There is a one-to-many relationship from `Garage` to `Car`,
- there is a many-to-many relationship from `Category` to `Car`,

and you want to count all cars which

- belong to one of the given garages (which should be active), and
- have at least one category of the given set of categories.

The first request can be done with

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "carInGarage.active = TRUE AND carInGarage IN %@", garages)
```

and the second with

```
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "ANY carHasCategories IN %@", categories)
```

and the combination with

```
let p = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2])
```

It *might* be that “ANY IN” does not work with many-to-many relationships,
in that case

```
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(carHasCategories,$c,$c IN %@").@count > 0, categories)
```

should do the job.